# Filtering ZSH history by command

Tags: filtering, history, zsh

I was told that in ZSH you could do something like `command` and then when you hit up it would filter the history based on the given command. But when I try this it just cycles the history like bash does. Is this disabled by default?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl+R`, type some letters, it will find the previous command with these letters, keep hitting Ctrl+R to continue through the previous findings.
Works in bash, zsh (and other shells i suppose).

What i personally like to have is: type some letters, press `Up`, the previous commands starting with the same letters appear. Very powerful, i love it.
You have to bind the keys you want to `history-beginning-search-backward` and `history-beginning-search-forward`.

In case it's not enough for you, zsh has a lot of options, try to look in [Zsh Line Editor](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_14.html) and tell us.
For bash, less powerful but more common, [Bash commands for history](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html).

Comment: See my answer for something very similar to what you described in your second paragraph. It does full substring search, so it matches any part of a command, but it should be quite easy to modify to only match from the start of commands.

Comment: `CTRL+R` won't work out of the gate if you're using Vim bindings in zsh.  If you are, trying adding `bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward` to your ~/.zshrc file.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14041933/461834) for instructions on setting the key binding to Up. You'll want lines that look like `bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward` and
`bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward`. Instead of typing the `^[[A` though, you'll want to hit Ctrl+V, Up within a terminal editor to get the right key code.

Comment: `"$terminfo[kcuu1]"`(up) and `"$terminfo[kcud1]"` (down) are both pretty solid on just about any newer dist, I think.

Comment: for those who miss blazing fast history navigation / filtering, I highly recommend `fzf` (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which does fuzzy search on `stdin` and perfectly integrates into zsh / bash via Ctrl-R keyboard shortcut (and more).

Answer (score 12):

Use exclamation point:

```
> !<starts-with this string>
```

You can arrow up/down through all commands that started with that. I use "!v" all the time to get my previous command for opening a file with Vim.

You can also use a question mark to search beyond matching the beginning of the string,

```
> !?status
```

Can find "git status".

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I type !vi and press Up and I see the previous command, not the previous command starting with "vi".  Is there a setting I have to turn on for this to work?

Comment: @LarryHastings, you have to press `Enter` first. Then you can press `Up` to go through command history.

Comment: Where is this syntax documented?

Comment: It is documented on the man page of the expansions, i.e. `man zshexpn`, search for `!?`.

See also the source for the man page:
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Doc/Zsh/expn.yo#L170

Answer (score 8):

We can also use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to fuzzy search the command history interactively.

Here is how to install:

```sh
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
~/.fzf/install
```

Say yes to all its configs. After that, restart your zsh shell, and press `Ctrl-R`, whoa, interactive command history search pops up. Enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

Use [percol](https://github.com/mooz/percol) to dynamically search and navigate through your history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

- install percol: `sudo pip install percol`
- add the [zsh-history-search](https://github.com/mooz/percol#zsh-history-search) code snippet to your .zshrc file.

After a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>, you can see your whole history in the same window. Searching for a keyword (dynamically) narrows that list down. You can use key-bindings (like this [emacs like](https://github.com/mooz/percol#configuration) config) to navigate up and down the list and eventually make a selection.

Here is a search for all `sudo install` commands available in history with `sudo make install` selected.

[image: percol_history_search_example]

<kbd>Enter</kbd> issues the selected command.

Answer (score 6):

With the vim keybindings activated in zsh you can use vi-history-search-backward (/) when in vi command mode.

Comment: This is actually great. Then you can hit `n` to go to the next item. Not sure how to display all though.

Comment: Wow, yes `n` will continue searching backwards in history. If you go too far `N` will search forward.

Answer (score 4):

That's a feature available in [fish](http://fishshell.com/), but it seems like someone made a [zsh plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) for it. It's not available in standard ZSH.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add any keybindings, you can search by default using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to move backward & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to move forward.

> You can start search with any of the key shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>